# Assign dates to predetermined periods using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

Say we have 2 df--please use `pd.read_clipboard()`:

`df_1`

```
Date
1995-03-12
1980-11-30
1972-03-05
1978-12-03
```

`df_2`

```
Period  From        To
39      1971-11-29  1975-11-30
40      1975-01-12  1979-11-25
41      1979-11-26  1983-11-27
42      1983-11-28  1987-11-29
43      1987-11-30  1991-11-24
44      1991-11-25  1995-12-03
45      1995-04-12  1999-12-05
```

Assume too that all dates are in format `datetime64[ns]`

**What I need is to assign the appropriate `Period` number from `df_2` to each date of `df_1`.**

**Desired output for `df_1`**:

```
Date        Period
1995-03-12  44
1980-11-30  41
1972-03-05  39
1978-12-03  40
```

I.e., a `Period` column was added to `df_1`, containing the appropriate period number as defined in `df_2`.

Note `df_2` should remain untouched, nor should it be merged with `df_1`.

The above is a sample. The actual `df_1` has hundreds of dates, and the actual `df_2` has fifty periods. Both also have many more columns.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `IntervalIndex`

```
df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.From,df2.To)
df1['Period'] = df2.loc[df1.Date,'Period'].values
df1
Out[16]: 
        Date  Period
0 1995-03-12      44
1 1980-11-30      41
2 1972-03-05      39
3 1978-12-03      40
```

Comment: Many thanks, BENY. This works perfectly on the sample, however, when I apply this solution to my actual full dataset, I get this error: `Length of values (731) does not match length of index (663)`. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Could it be because some dates have been assigned several periods, thereby resulting in a longer dataframe?

Comment: @johnjohn yes , that is correct

Comment: Fixed now! Many thanks again and answer accepted.